# High CPU usage onloading content by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this JS code to preview audio file before it's being uploaded

```
uaudio.onchange = function() {
    var soundiv = document.getElementById('soundiv');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    soundiv.style.display = "block";
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var osos = document.getElementById("closeb");
        $('#sound').attr('src', this.result);
        osos.style.display = "inline-block"; 
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
```

It loads the file successfuly, but it causes high CPU usage.

What should i do?

Comment: Nothing you can do in JS. CPU utilisation will be determined by the browsers underlying logic which handles the file IO

Comment: It's worth nothing, though, that a simple audio element shouldn't be causing *that* much CPU usage, even for a large file.

Comment: How high is the usage? And why do you think the usage is problematic?